# How do I prevent raspberry pi automatic turn on when I connect the power plug?

Tags: pi-4, power-supply, raspi-config, power-management, alternative-power

[image]

I connect the power in plug. After that raspberry pi automatically turn on .
But I want it to be on when I press the button, how can I do this?

Comment: Can you describe exactly your scenario? Don't try to simplify it.
Also, are you able to solder stuff? Are you able to power the raspberry from the 40pin header?
Also. Would something like this work for you?
https://howchoo.com/g/mwnlytk3zmm/how-to-add-a-power-button-to-your-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way the Pi is designed to work.
Connecting power causes it to boot.

It has NO means of turning power on or off (without external hardware).

You may be able to find additional hardware to do this but there is little point unless you are running from battery.

Comment: Can I direct power off / disconnect power. Use turn off process most important ? YES/NOT

Comment: I am not sure what your comment means. Do not ask new questions in Comments - either edit your Question or ask another.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply wire a SPST switch in series with the 5V USB power plug. This could be done as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDL0z8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For something a bit more useful, you might consider using the following circuit which employs a "latching relay" in conjunction with the `GPIO-POWEROFF` Device Tree Overlay. When the `START` pushbutton is pressed, this circuit applies power to the RPi (causing it to boot). The RPi will then run until the `GPIO-POWEROFF` overlay is invoked by issuing a `halt` command from the terminal, at which point the RPi goes through a "safe" shutdown before removing power from the RPi input. Used in this way, the Latching relay "toggles" power ON and OFF using the `START` pushbutton, and a `halt` command from the terminal - or timed using `cron`, etc.

Many other schemes for powering the Pi ON & OFF are possible using variations on this design.

[image]